# Basic jQuery Slider does not display properly on page load (Responsive setting)

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm using the latest bjqs and jquery versions. I'm not editing ANY bjqs css. The issue is when the page loads, the second image is in the view. The slides continue this as they slide in where the other image is visible. However if I resize the window in any way the bjqs does what it is supposed to do and it resizes the images so only one is visible.

I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3edFN.jpg

This is my markup.

```
<div id="container"> 
<-- slider in here -->
</div>

#container {max-width: 1600px;}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#banner-slide').bjqs({
animtype      : 'slide',
height        : 520,
width         : 1600,
responsive    : true,
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm reproducing something similar here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ru5vp/2

html:

```
    <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
    <ul class="bjqs">
        <li><img src="http://www.basic-slider.com/img/banner01.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.basic-slider.com/img/banner02.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.basic-slider.com/img/banner03.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

  </div>
  <!-- End outer wrapper -->
```

css:

```
ul.bjqs{position:relative; list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden; display:none;}
li.bjqs-slide{position:absolute; display:none;}
ul.bjqs-controls{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:9999;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{position:absolute;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a{right:0;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a{left:0;}
ol.bjqs-markers{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;}
ol.bjqs-markers.h-centered{text-align: center;}
ol.bjqs-markers li{display:inline;}
ol.bjqs-markers li a{display:inline-block;}
p.bjqs-caption{display:block;width:96%;margin:0;padding:2%;position:absolute;bottom:0;}
#container {max-width: 1600px;}
```

jQuery initialization:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype      : 'slide',
        height        : 520,
        width         : 1600,
        responsive    : true,
    });
});
```

The dimensions of the images are different from what is declared in the js height and width. If I change the dimensions to be equal to the actual dimensions, it works fine.

I notice that if I use `height: 826, width: 1600`, which scales the images proportionally, the images are setup similar to what your image shows. If I resize the result window, the images resize like what you are describing.